# Why does bind_param not fail if I pass a string even though it is marked as "i" (integer)?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, php-7

I am wondering why the following mysqli statement works even though I pass a string and it expects an integer.

```
$id = "A";

$sql = "SELECT m.mandator_id, longname, shortname"
     . " FROM mandator m "
     . " WHERE mandator_id != ? "
     . " ORDER BY mandator_id";

$err = "";
if (!$stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql)) {
    $err .= "Prepare failed: (" . $this->con->errno . ") " . $this->con->error;
}
if (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $id)) {
    $err .= "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
...
```

I stepped over the code but the part "Binding parameters failed" is not reached

> ```
>                                     Type specification chars
> ```
>
> Character      |                    Description
>
> **i**      |    corresponding variable has type integer
>
> **d**       |   corresponding variable has type double
>
> **s** | corresponding variable has type string
>
> **b** | corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets

[Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: PHP being a loosely typed language (although PHP 7 is striving to fix that), I am *guessing* that mysqli simply typecasts your input variable to integer. In this case, it will become 0.

Comment: It is *MySQL* is a loosely typed database actually.

Comment: good question tho

Comment: @YourCommonSense agree that MySQL is also a loosely typed RDBMS (that is why they both get together a lot !); but if `mysqli` is not implicitly handling input based on "type specifier", then what is the point of providing "type specifier" at all ? Maybe I am missing some point here !

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya good question. I think I would test and see. Doe example PDO will bind a string if you pass a string no matter if PARAM_INT is used

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya as far as I can tell you were right, mysqli silently casts a string value before sending it to database. I could open the question if you are willing to make it an answer